# Where are "10 Days of Swampy" and "Hearts and Crafts"?

Tags: achievements, wheres-my-water

Two of the achievments in *Where's My Water?* are for "tri-ducking" "10 Days of Swampy" and "Hearts and Crafts".  I have searched and searched in the game and can't find these worlds anywhere.  **Where are they and how do I get them?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are level packages located inside "The Lost Levels".

[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: If you have a graphics program, I'd suggest shrinking those images to half the size, they came up pretty huge here.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, done